# Does StarCraft 2 ignore my OSes mouse sensitivity settings?

Tags: starcraft-2, mouse

I recently purchased a [Razer Mamba mouse](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-mice/razer-mamba). While I have been satisfied with the mouse it can be hyper sensitive. I haven't found the right feel yet for Windows or for StarCraft, but I cannot tell if my OS tweaks are affecting the game. Are my operating systems mouse sensitivity settings overridden by the settings in the StarCraft 2 Controls Menu?

[image: Screenshot of Controls Menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a check box for that right at the top of screenshot. "Enable Mouse Sensitivity". Read that tooltip.

Comment: If you post the Screen Shot of the tool tip, this will improve your answer and make it easier to future users.